# Java Error when trying to parse an XML stream

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I create a url that will trigger our GSA to return an XML reply. I have double checked that the url generation is working.

When i try to parse the stream using the following line of code:

```
Document doc = (Document) db.parse(new URL(filePath).openStream());
```

In the system log I get the following errors:

```
Error: URI=null Line=2: Document root element "GSP", must match DOCTYPE root "null"
Error: URI=null Line=2: Document is invalid: no grammar found
```

XML File looks something like this (i have used xxx to blank out identifying information):

```
<GSP VER="3.2">
<TM>0.011504</TM>
<Q>xxxxxxx</Q>
<PARAM name="output" value="xml_no_dtd" original_value="xml_no_dtd"/>
<PARAM name="q" value="xxxxxxx" original_value="xxxxxxx"/>
<PARAM name="site" value="xxxxxxx" original_value="xxxxxxx"/>
<PARAM name="btn" value="" original_value=""/>
<PARAM name="ie" value="UTF-8" original_value="UTF-8"/>
<PARAM name="ip" value="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" original_value="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"/>
<PARAM name="access" value="p" original_value="p"/>
<PARAM name="sort" value="date:D:L:d1" original_value="date:D:L:d1"/>
</GSP>
```

Has anyone dealt with an issue like this before that may be able to provide some measure of guidance?

Comment: What's `db`? What are the contents of the xml document? Try assigning the result of calling `openStream()` to a variable and checking that it is not `null`. (This is a good idea anway so you can close the stream after parsing.)

Comment: i will add the xml to the main question

Comment: db is the name i gave to my DocumentBuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DocumentBuilder` has validation enabled, but you don't have a DTD defined (alternative: your defined DTD does not match the actual content).

Comment: in this case if i disable validation the issue may go away ?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? Look for a call to `setValidating(true)`, and either delete it or pass `false`.

Comment: because to try it i have to push it to production. to push it to production i have to scan the code. if i scan the code and im not validating the DB i will need to justify it. and more than likely they are not going to let me slide with "i think this may possibly work " ;)  Im trying to find something more concrete to tell the higher ups before i disable it.

Comment: You can only test in production ?!? Start by telling the higher-ups that's insane.

Comment: But, since you need a reason, here's a definition from the [XML Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/): "An XML document is valid if it has an associated document type declaration and if the document complies with the constraints expressed in it". In other words, if you don't have a DTD, it makes no sense to turn validation on.

Comment: this seems right. and would make complete sense.... as far as having no GSA in the dev environment i completely agree... but They make the bigger bucks. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I'm at work at the moment but my advice is take a look at Jaxb.  It has amazing annotation support and is often used in frameworks that deal with xml.

It's a safe bet the Jaxb will make your life easier.